# What the easiest way to create MySQL db for Django in Azure without using ClearDB?

Tags: django, database, azure

I am trying to create django project with MySQL db in Azure. Here is tutorial how to do it: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-ptvs-django-mysql/#create-a-mysql-database . It says I should use ClearDB or create Virtual Machine and install and administer MySQL. Please advise tutorial or tell in a nutshell how to go second way (or some else way).

Comment: ClearDB is a MySQL database: https://www.cleardb.com/  Creating a virtual machine on a cloud-hosted solution just to run database server doesn't sound very efficient. Most *nix environments natively support a MySQL server install. Is there any reason you need Azure, or don't want to use ClearDB?

Comment: Yes. I have trial credit on Azure and I can't use It with ClearDB